# It is possible to create a translator for my angular application?

Tags: angular, .net-core

I create an application with angular for front end and .net core for back end.

I want to know if there is a way to translate a word in my application with my own tools (**angular,.net-core and postgresql**) ?

For example, in my application there is the work **Welcome** if the user have french for language the word shown will be **Bienvenue**.

Comment: check this
https://github.com/robisim74/angular-l10n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the static words you can use the internationalization(i18n). here is a link to the official guide:
https://angular.io/guide/i18n

You can also use the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core),I personally use it because it is easy-going

Comment: Just a question, if a word is not translate in a language but it's translate in the default language it will automatically select the word translate in default language ?

Comment: with ngx-translate you can precise that, with a condition

Answer (score 1):

Refer this :
[Angular translator](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular8-app-with-ngx-translate)